# how to convert an array of strings to classes to call movieclips from my library? as3 cs5

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array of ingredients for soup as strings. These ingredients are also movieclips in my library, all linked with an identifier. I want to add the movieclips to the stage dynamically.

I tried getDefinitionByName but I keep getting an error that the variable "appel" (veg[0] in this case) is undefined. 
And basically, I only have a general idea what I'm doing here, so I would be grateful if someone could explain it to me or link me to a helpful tutorial.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

public class groentesoep extends MovieClip {
    const xAr:Array = [13,163,13,26,133,192,169,301,47,313,286,291,163,16];
    const yAr:Array = [12,133,133,370,484,352,256,316,241,160,468,10,53,465];                          
    const veg:Array = ["appel","bloemkool","broccoli","brood","champignons","friet","kaas","melk","paprika","prei","tomaat","ui","vis","wortel"];

    var i:int;

    public function groentesoep() {
        // constructor code
        create_intro();
    }
    public function create_intro () {
        var bord:intro = new intro();
        bord.x = -30;
        bord.y = -6;
        bord.name = "intro";
        addChild(bord);

        var btn:begin = new begin();
        btn.x = 416;
        btn.y = 255;
        btn.name = "beginKnop";
        btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, create_spel);
        addChild(btn);
    }
    public function create_spel(event:MouseEvent) {
        removeChild(getChildByName("intro"));
        getChildByName("beginKnop").removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, create_spel);
        removeChild(getChildByName("beginKnop"));

        var bord:spel = new spel();
        bord.x = -30;
        bord.y = -6;
        bord.name = "spel";
        addChild(bord);         

        var c:Class = getDefinitionByName(veg[0]) as Class;
        var instance:Object = new c();
        var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(instance);
        addChild(mc);
    }
}}
```

[Screenshot of library](http://i39.tinypic.com/i762ig.jpg)

Comment: Could you please trace c and instance just before the error?

Comment: I traced them as you said. But the error seems to refer this bit getDefinitionByName(veg[0]) as Class and instance can't be traced because of that. I think the error means he doesn't recognise veg[0] (the string "appel") as a class.

Comment: You mean "trace(c)" just after "var c:Class = ..." displays "null"?

Comment: No, I mean that he doesn't even get that far. The error is this: ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variabele appel is undefined.

Comment: Well then "appel" is really not available in the library. I can't load the picture you uploaded, make sure you have no typo in your linknames.

Comment: the link is corrected now and appel is the first one in the library

Comment: Strange! I'm sorry I can't think of anything else, maybe if you uploaded you fla and as...

Comment: I accepted the answer below. Apparently you first have to mention your linked movieclip class before you can actually do antyhing with it. Thanks for thinking along with me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using getDefinitionByName, you always have to explicitly use the classes in your code.
That means that if you're using the class which name is defined in veg [0] - "appel" - you have to "force" the compiler to include that class.
Just wrote at the beginning of your code:

```
 var dummyAppel:appel;
```

...and do it for all the classes you want to retrieve by their names.
Hope it helps

Comment: You're welcome. I lost lot of time because of it too, it's not straightforward at all :(  I think this happens because the compiler skips all unused classes, and this is the only way to make it aware of the class in your library you're going to use

Comment: Nice one. To simplify everything you could even put classes in your array instead of class names :)

Answer (score 0):

When using `getDefinitionByName` with a library, you must make sure your clips are linked. Check the linkage column in your library, this is this alias that will be used as a class name.

Comment: They are linked and the names correspond to the strings in the array veg[]. So that can't be the problem at this point.

Comment: @Kodiak I too have the feeling that this is the problem.

Comment: @silvith maybe if you print screen your library(like in my answer), we might see something you're not seeing.

Comment: I added a link to a screenshot of the library - my restrictions won't allow me to post images here yet :) Thanks both of you, for your help btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach you can take which you can see in this example:

The following is an image of two movieclip symbols in the library:

[image]

I store their class names in a `Vector.<String>` constant in the document class.

**Main.as(document class):**

```
package  
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

    public class Main extends MovieClip 
    {
        private const SHAPES:Vector.<String> = 
            Vector.<String>(['Circle', 'Square']);

        private var classes:Dictionary;

        public function Main() 
        {
            setClasses();

            addChild(new classes['Square']());

        }// end function

        private function setClasses():void
        {
            var classes:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

            for each(var shape:String in SHAPES)
            {
                classes[shape] = getDefinitionByName(shape);

            }// end for each

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Comment: This option is a bit too complicated for me at this point. Thanks for your input though :)

Comment: @silvith well it isn't really that complicated when explained(which I should have done). `private const SHAPES:Vector.<String> = Vector.<String>(['Circle', 'Square']);` is basically the same as `private const SHAPES:Array = ['Circle', 'Square'];`. It doesn't make that much difference which you use. As for the `Dictionary` object `classes`, that is basically like an array but instead of using an integer as the index, you use a key that is associated with the value you want, hence `classes['Square']` which is the equivalent of `Square` which we can initiate like this `new classes['Square']();`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think I understand what you mean, but I'll have to experiment a bit to get used to this approach :)